# QUEUEABLE TEST CLASS

Tags: wrapper-class, test-setup, queueable-apex

I have a request to create a queueable test class where the test class is to use @testsetup using a testdatafactory returning a complex wrapper class.

The idea is the testDataFactor should populate the wrapperClass and return the populated data then I want to use it in a test aka test1 (see below).

How can I access WC returned by the testdatafactory in test1?

```
@isTest
public with sharing class queueableClassTest
{
   @TestSetup
   static void makeData()
   {
     wrapperClass WC = testDataFactory.MethodSetup();
   }

   @isTest
   static test1 void()
   {
     QueueableClassname QC = new QueueableClassName(WC);

     test.startTest();
     id apexJobID = system.enqueueJob(QC);
     test.stopTest();

     systemAssertNotEquals(null, apexJobID);

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this can be done but only in a fragile way and not recommended

You could do this:

```
public with sharing class queueableClassTest {
   static wrapperClass WC;
   @TestSetup
   static void makeData()
   {
   WC = testDataFactory.MethodSetup();
   }
```

but this only works if you have exactly one(1) testmethod in the class. If you have two+ methods, the value in WC is cleared before the second test is run (and order of which testmethods execute is inderterminate)

This is covered extensively in this [Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdX0YUAV/remember-static-variables-set-during-testsetup-annotated-methods) and this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/140551/any-good-reason-test-method-will-clear-up-static-variable-values-set-by-testsetu)

> We intentionally clear out static variables between each test method.  If we did not, each test would cease to be an independent trial. You could modify the static in one test method, which would make the order in which tests operate relevant to the results.  This is precisely what you don't want - data dependent tests.
> If you want information that is common to all tests, it can be inserted in the test setup method and queried in each test method.  The idea here is not to reduce the number of SOQL queries, it is to reduce the amount of data being inserted into the system.  If you insert 1000 records in test setup, run fifteen test methods, and you run a query 15 times to get the 1000 records each time, that's still less expensive (and faster) than inserting 1000 records 15 times.

@testSetup is designed to do DML in a time-efficient manner which you must requery in each testmethod that needs the objects.

What you could do is not use @TestSetup at all and call the `testFactory.methodSetup()` in each method that needs a `wrapperClass`

*Aside:
I'd suggest you make your classNames start with capitals and method names start lowercase to conform to SFDC Apex conventions*

Comment: Thanks Cropredy.  I do imagine having more than 1 test.  I know how to handle Sobject types and then query for the object in the test but the wrapper class doesn't have something I can query for in the test method.  I was hoping someone had encountered this before and there might be an elegant solution.  I was hoping to avoid the solution you put forth.  Based on your answer I had the same thought to create a method in the factory for each test.  You are right about the naming conventions; I was going more for concept than technical but thanks for calling it out.